# Loading a div based on the content of an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am displaying an iframe that changes content dynamically after about 30 seconds. I one instance when the iframe has the text `<h3>You are being redirected</h3>`, I would to add a div on to my page and when the redirection text disapappers from the iframe, the added div should disappear as well.

Wondering, if this is actually possible and whether it could actually be done with jQuery?

Comment: don't use jquery while using angular. Please provide the relevant code you have tried so far

Comment: Is the iframe served from the same domain as the containing page, or from a different domain?

Comment: @MichaelGeary it is from a different domain

Comment: Then unfortunately you have no access to the content of the iframe. You will have to look for another solution, sorry.